# MVC ASP.net Creating a generic helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, helper

I have two view models, `PublishedSong` and `RadioStation` where I want them to have `IncrementViews(int id)` function.

Instead of copying and pasting the function in to both controllers I wanted to make a generic helper class.

Helper:

```
public class CustomDBHelper<T>
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetElements(ApplicationDbContext db, T type)
    {
        if (type.Equals(typeof(SongsController)))
            return (IEnumerable<T>)db.PublishedSongs;
        else if (type.Equals(typeof(RadioStationsController)))
            return (IEnumerable<T>)db.RadioStations;
        else
            throw new Exception("Controller not found, DBHelper");
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class MusicBaseController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult IncrementViews(int id)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            db.PublishedSongs.Single(x => x.Id == id);
            var element = CustomDBHelper<T>.GetElements(db, this.GetType()).Single(x => x.Id == id);
            element.UniquePlayCounts++;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { UniquePlayCounts = element.UniquePlayCounts }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

I am having trouble with this line: `var element = CustomDBHelper<T>.GetElements(db, this.GetType()).Single(x => x.Id == id);`

The `<T>` is invalid. I am new to generics, I think it expects a class but because the class could either be `PublishedSong` or `RadioStation` I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Why do you need to such a function anyway? Why do you need to access properties by type?

Comment: Because otherwise I would have to duplicate code in controllers

Comment: Is my solution helpful?

Comment: I can't test it ATM. Will tell you later.

Answer (score -1):

The following implementation will work for you:

```
public class CustomDBHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable GetElements(ApplicationDbContext db, Type type)
    {
        if (type.Equals(typeof(SongsController)))
        {
            return db.PublishedSongs;
        }
        else if (type.Equals(typeof(RadioStationsController)))
        {
            return db.RadioStations;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Controller not found, DBHelper");
        }
    }
}
```

And you will need to cast the result of this function to the required type.

On a side note, type generics are used, well, for being type generic. Since you pass the type as a parameter it's not necessary.

Comment: `.Single(x => x.Id == id)` Error 1 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Single' and no extension method 'Single' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Try adding "using System.Linq" at the top of your file.

Comment: Didn't work. Still no query methods on `CustomDBHelper.GetElements(db, this.GetType())`

Comment: Perform "Cast" on the resulted IEnumerable with the desired type.